# Python - Pyramid and matplotlib - Cannot Have More Than One View Output A SVG?

Tags: python, svg, matplotlib, pyramid, cstringio

I am developing a Python Pyramid application where I am intending to create more than one SVG image to chart statistics using pie charts. In my testing I find that one SVG view works correctly and as soon as I add a second SVG output view, and a second SVG image is loaded (order of SVG image load doesn't matter), whether directly through its view, or through another view that references this view, the SVG images "are combined" in any other further calls to load a SVG file. This appears to be a bug somewhere in the Python stack as it appears memory is not cleared properly (primarily in the case of more than one SVG file, see further details below). Also note below that after enough image/page loads a TclError is encountered.

Since I was using SVG in a more detailed application with many more views, I am reproducing this in a minimized/reduced application to show it isn't something extra I'm doing and this code is generated right from the Pyramid *alchemy* template and database calls are not involved. The database is actively utilized in my more details application. This application only has 3 views, where the first view is part of the original template. I am also adding DEBUG logging to make it clear that there is *no indication* that there is any internal calling of the other SVG view.

Some of the view code is based on [Matplotlib svg as string and not a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453375/matplotlib-svg-as-string-and-not-a-file) primarily for the use of `StringIO`. Note that as a pie chart is needed, that is the primary reason why my code differs from the code in referenced question. I find the issue is essentially the same whether I use `StringIO` or `cStringIO`. In my code I am using `cStringIO`.

The full application code is available at: https://github.com/danielpronych/pyramidapp

PyPlot Documentation:: [pyplot api](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html)

**Update: Code From First SVG View (figure handles and a close command):**

```
@view_config(route_name='view_test_svg')
def test_svg_view(request):
    # Full module import is not allowed by Pyramid
    #from pylab import *
    # Do individual required imports instead
    from pylab import close, figure, axes, pie, title, savefig
    # For clarity, note that the above, and below, function the same
    #from matplotlib.pyplot import close, figure, axes, pie, title, savefig
    log.debug('In test_svg_view')
    fig = figure(1, figsize=(6,6))
    ax = axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
    labels = ['Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs']
    fracs = [15, 30, 45, 10]
    explode=(0, 0.05, 0, 0)
    pie(fracs, explode=explode, labels=labels,
                                autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
    title('Raining Hogs and Dogs', bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':5})
    imgdata = cStringIO.StringIO()
    fig.savefig(imgdata, format='svg')
    imgdata.seek(0)
    svg_dta = imgdata.getvalue()
    # Close the StringIO buffer
    imgdata.close()
    close('all')
    return Response(svg_dta, content_type='image/svg+xml')
```

***Steps For This Code***:

1. Load http://localhost:6543/test.svg
2. Load http://localhost:6543/test2.svg
3. Load either (1) or (2) again. The `pserve` will "spin" continuously with no sign from the command window why.

*Note:* Loading the same SVG view 3 times with this code also has the same result as the steps above which **does not** occur with the code below.

Also note that [pyplot pie](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pie) does have a return; however, not a "handle" per se.

- `pserve` window does not respond to Control+C commands, even after waiting over a minute (particularly after doing the steps above).

**Code From First SVG View (original, steps below are from this code):**

```
@view_config(route_name='view_test_svg')
def test_svg_view(request):
    # Full module import is not allowed by Pyramid
    #from pylab import *
    # Do individual required imports instead
    from pylab import figure, axes, pie, title, savefig
    # For clarity, note that the above, and below, function the same
    #from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, axes, pie, title, savefig
    log.debug('In test_svg_view')
    figure(1, figsize=(6,6))
    ax = axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
    labels = ['Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs']
    fracs = [15, 30, 45, 10]
    explode=(0, 0.05, 0, 0)
    pie(fracs, explode=explode, labels=labels,
                                autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
    title('Raining Hogs and Dogs', bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':5})
    imgdata = cStringIO.StringIO()
    savefig(imgdata, format='svg')
    imgdata.seek(0)
    svg_dta = imgdata.getvalue()
    # Close the StringIO buffer
    imgdata.close()
    return Response(svg_dta, content_type='image/svg+xml')
```

**Python Version:** Python 2.7.5

**Python Package Configuration (Primary Packages Only)**

- pyramid-1.6a1-py2.7
- matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-win32

**Steps Taken To Reproduce:**

1. pserve pyramidapp.

Command: `pserve development.ini --reload`

```
Starting server in PID 4912.
serving on http://0.0.0.0:6543
```

2. Load http://localhost:6543/test.svg

Note this works properly

```
DEBUG [pyramidapp.views:22][Dummy-2] In test_svg_view
```

[image: Step 2 image]

3. Load http://localhost:6543/test2.svg

Note this "combines" both SVG files together

```
DEBUG [pyramidapp.views:45][Dummy-3] In test2_svg_view
```

[image: Step 3 image]

4. Load http://localhost:6543/test.svg

Note this works exactly like test2.svg, with the correct title, since they are also of similar length, and now images are combined in this view as well

```
DEBUG [pyramidapp.views:22][Dummy-4] In test_svg_view
```

[image: Step 4 image]

5. Rehost application and only load http://localhost:6543/test2.svg

Note this works properly for first load as this view was loaded before test.svg this time

```
DEBUG [pyramidapp.views:45][Dummy-2] In test2_svg_view
```

[image: Step 5 image]

**Tracelog when using Control+C to terminate the pserve process**

```
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "--python_path--\lib\atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "--python_path--\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-win32.egg\ma
tplotlib\_pylab_helpers.py", line 89, in destroy_all
    manager.destroy()
  File "--python_path--\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-win32.egg\ma
tplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 588, in destroy
    self.window.destroy()
  File "--python_path--\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1789, in destroy
    for c in self.children.values(): c.destroy()
  File "--python_path--\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2042, in destroy
    self.tk.call('destroy', self._w)
_tkinter.TclError: out of stack space (infinite loop?)
^C caught in monitor process
```

**Important: After enough SVG image loads the following is encountered:**

The only way to *fix* this currently is to restart `pserve`. Also note that views, such as the `my_view` load properly as long as SVG images are not referenced, or utilized, by such views.

Another important note, as long as only one SVG file, i.e. http://localhost:6543/test.svg, is loaded the entire time of `pserve` it seems that image can be reloaded/refreshed (potentially) infinite times without any apparent issue, or encountering of the following:

[image: _tkinter header]

```
_tkinter.TclError
TclError: out of stack space (infinite loop?)
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "--python_path--\lib\site-packages\pyramid_debugtoolbar-2.0.2-py2.7.egg\pyramid_debugtoolbar\panels

\performance.py", line 69, in noresource_timer_handler
Display the sourcecode for this frameOpen an interactive python shell in this frameresult = handler(request)
File "--python_path--\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.6a1-py2.7.egg\pyramid\tweens.py", line 20, in excview_tween
Display the sourcecode for this frameOpen an interactive python shell in this frameresponse = handler(request)
File "--python_path--\lib\site-packages\pyramid_tm-0.11-py2.7.egg\pyramid_tm\__init__.py", line 94, in tm_tween
Display the sourcecode for this frameOpen an interactive python shell in this framereraise(*exc_info)
File "--python_path--\lib\site-packages\pyramid_tm-0.11-py2.7.egg\pyramid_tm\__init__.py", line 75, in tm_tween
Display the sourcecode for this frameOpen an interactive python shell in this frameresponse = handler(request)
File "--python_path--\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.6a1-py2.7.egg\pyramid\router.py", line 145, in handle_request
Display the sourcecode for this frameOpen an interactive python shell in this frameview_name
File "--python_path--\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.6a1-py2.7.egg\pyramid\view.py", line 527, in _call_view
Display the sourcecode for this frameOpen an interactive python shell in this frameresponse = view_callable

(context, request)
File "--python_path--\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.6a1-py2.7.egg\pyramid\config\views.py", line 384, in 

viewresult_to_response
Display the sourcecode for this frameOpen an interactive python shell in this frameresult = view(context, 

request)
File "--python_path--\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.6a1-py2.7.egg\pyramid\config\views.py", line 506, in 

_requestonly_view
Display the sourcecode for this frameOpen an interactive python shell in this frameresponse = view(request)
File "c:\projects\python\pyramid\pyramidapp\pyramidapp\views.py", line 55, in test2_svg_view
Display the sourcecode for this frameOpen an interactive python shell in this framesavefig(imgdata, 

format='svg')
File "--python_path--\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-win32.egg\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 578, in 

savefig
Display the sourcecode for this frameOpen an interactive python shell in this framedraw()   # need this if 

'transparent=True' to reset colors
File "--python_path--\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-win32.egg\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 571, in 

draw
Display the sourcecode for this frameOpen an interactive python shell in this frameget_current_fig_manager

().canvas.draw()
File "--python_path--\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-win32.egg\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", 

line 350, in draw
Display the sourcecode for this frameOpen an interactive python shell in this frametkagg.blit(self._tkphoto, 

self.renderer._renderer, colormode=2)
File "--python_path--\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-win32.egg\matplotlib\backends\tkagg.py", line 

24, in blit
Display the sourcecode for this frameOpen an interactive python shell in this frametk.call("PyAggImagePhoto", 

photoimage, id(aggimage), colormode, id(bbox_array))
TclError: out of stack space (infinite loop?)
```

**Update (September 2015):** I was hoping to see a further update from Sergey, since his suggested solution did seem to help at first; however, the issue was not resolved with his solution, since none has happened even though I've waited a considerable amount of time, I found that only my solution actually resolved this issue. Lastly, to be clear, my solution works in the web-based implementation and in batch processing as this issue surfaces in batch processing as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer provided by Sergey was definitely helpful. I was able to find that if added a few more pieces to the code, based on portions of this [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/misc/svg_filter_pie.html), including a `matplotlib.use` statement, the memory issues seem to be resolved. I tested this both in my test application (2 views generating a SVG file, posted above) and my primary application which currently has 3 SVG views, which I will expand to more views creating SVG files.

With my primary application, I can refresh between all 3 existing views, multiple times, without the *SVG image combining* that I found with prior versions of this code. The setting seems necessary for more **concurrent** uses which may be why other SO questions don't seem to reflect this issue, unless I am able to find something else that is causing this issue. I am not sure if this is the best answer; however, this does appear to work correctly for now and I plan to monitor to see if any other issues are found.

```
@view_config(route_name='view_test_svg')
def test_svg_view(request):
    from matplotlib import use as matplotlib_use
    matplotlib_use("Svg")
    from matplotlib.pyplot import close, figure, axes, pie, title, savefig
    log.debug('In test_svg_view')
    fig = figure(1, figsize=(6,6))
    ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
    labels = ['Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs']
    fracs = [15, 30, 45, 10]
    explode=(0, 0.05, 0, 0)
    pie(fracs, explode=explode, labels=labels,
                                autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
    title('Raining Hogs and Dogs', bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':5})
    imgdata = cStringIO.StringIO()
    savefig(imgdata, format='svg')
    imgdata.seek(0)
    svg_dta = imgdata.getvalue()
    # Close the StringIO buffer
    imgdata.close()
    close('all')
    return Response(svg_dta, content_type='image/svg+xml')
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the root of your problem is calling `plt.figure(1)`.  When you do that, you're telling matplotlib to return the same figure object each time, if possible.  Use `fig = figure(figsize=(6,6))` instead.  If you're going to use `pyplot`, close the figure at the end.  Otherwise the interactive backends will keep a reference to it.  However, it still a good idea to use a non-interactive backend (e.g. `Svg` or `Agg`) for webservers.  In this case, it would be better to avoid `pyplot` entirely, however.  That way you can guarentee that  the figure is garbage collected.

Comment: @JoeKington Thanks for this note, I also found, in extensive testing, a definition such as `matplotlib.use("Svg")` should still be used even when not outputting SVG files, such as PNG files -- this works, seems necessary, still, based on the above code, however, the `use()` routine does not accept "PNG" as an input. So you are saying not using figure(1, ...) would resolve this issue? Note also that this issue continues to exist in the suggested tutorials: i.e. http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html#working-with-multiple-figures-and-axes ... `plt.figure(1)` ...

Comment: To output PNG files, the backend will actually be temporarily switched to `Agg`. However, yes, you should use one of the non-interactive backends for a webserver.  Typically this is `Agg`.   `savefig` switches the backend to the approriate backend if the current one doesn't support the format. On a side note, any tutorial telling you to use `plt.figure(1)` is out of date.  That's only provided for matlab compatibility.  `plt.figure(1)` was the reason that multiple figures were being combined in your original question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with pylab, but it looks like the module has some global state, which is accumulated between calls (note how you invoke `savefig()` without passing it any sort of handle to your chart created by the previous calls - yet somehow it is supposed to know what has been drawn. So, I guess the subsequent calls just accumulate in the same "buffer", which explains the behaviour you're observing.

Here's an excerpt from the docs (emphasis mine):

> Therefore, everything in matplotlib is organized in a hierarchy. At
>   the top of the hierarchy is the matplotlib **“state-machine environment”**
>   which is provided by the matplotlib.pyplot module. At this level,
>   simple functions are used to add plot elements (lines, images, text,
>   etc.) **to the current axes in the current figure**.
>
> Note Pyplot’s **state-machine** environment behaves similarly to MATLAB
>   and should be most familiar to users with MATLAB experience. The next
>   level down in the hierarchy is the first level of the object-oriented
>   interface, in which pyplot is used only for a few functions such as
>   figure creation, and the user explicitly creates and keeps track of
>   the figure and axes objects. At this level, the user uses pyplot to
>   create figures, and through those figures, one or more axes objects
>   can be created. These axes objects are then used for most plotting
>   actions.
>
> For even more control – which is essential for things like embedding
>   matplotlib plots in GUI applications – **the pyplot level may be dropped
>   completely, leaving a purely object-oriented approach**.

This "state machine" approach may be ok for a "linear" script which processes some
data and exits I can't see how it could work in the web environment
(consider concurrent requests etc.)

I'm wondering if using "raw" Matplotlib (called "object-oriented approach" in their docs) would allow you to avoid the problem - from what I can see its API is more traditional - you create an instance of a Figure class and call its methods to create your chart, so all the state is incapsulated within that instance and is not stored between requests.

Here's an example in Matplotlib docs: [agg_oo.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/agg_oo.html). Note that it completely avoids the use of pylab and pyplot (the latter actually implements the "state machine layer").

I would imagine the code could look something like this (untested):

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

@view_config(route_name='view_test_svg')
def test_svg_view(request):
    fig = Figure(figsize=(6,6))
    ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
    labels = ['Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs']
    fracs = [15, 30, 45, 10]
    explode=(0, 0.05, 0, 0)
    ax.pie(
        fracs, explode=explode, labels=labels,
        autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
    ax.set_title('Raining Hogs and Dogs', bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':5})
    imgdata = cStringIO.StringIO()
    fig.savefig(imgdata, format='svg')
    imgdata.seek(0)
    svg_dta = imgdata.getvalue()
    # Close the StringIO buffer
    imgdata.close()
    return Response(svg_dta, content_type='image/svg+xml')
```

Comment: Please note, specifically in terms of the pylab name, see the PyPi package site for matplotlib, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib , as there is text that reads: **There is a ‘pylab’ mode which emulates matlab graphics.** Also note that the use of `savefig` is similar to those used in other SO questions such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041627/how-to-make-pylab-savefig-save-image-for-maximized-window-instead-of-default (to a `StringIO` instance as the first parameter and the format=svg as an additional parameter. Thanks for pointing this out, this does appear consistent.

Comment: In terms of docs, consider [pyplot api](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) and that the [pie](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pie) has no handle. Adding a handle to `figure`, `savefig`, and a `close` of the figure help slightly, both SVG files are now loaded correctly in sequence without having both combined **except** a third load (either image) now  spins the web browser with no indication from `pcreate` that a hang may be occurring. I will update my question with the code changes shortly. Issue still not resolved.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Note that the problem has nothing to do with your use of cStringIO - rather, I believe that it's being caused by the "state machine" architecture of pyplot, which is used by pylab. A global state is something you want to avoid in a web application.

Comment: Also note that `close(fig)` or `close('all')` only partially assists in freeing some memory. This assists if loading one SVG and following by loading the other SVG (they are not combined). However, this updated code can also make the web browser communicating with `pserve` "spin" endlessly even with only loading the same SVG view 3 times (whereas the first code could open the same SVG potentially infinite times without an issue). Lastly, `pserve` doesn't show this occurring, it just shows the third debug and the command window will not respond to commands such as Control+C.

Comment: @localhost: your updated question still make use of pyplot. Have you tried the "OO approach" as demonstrated in the example I linked to?

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that [OO example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/agg_oo.html). The challenge I would have with it is that doesn't use a pie chart which is still what I need to be able to create. The example code is based on [pie char demo features](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_demo_features.html); however, there the `show()` routine is used and I need a string because the view generates a SVG with `savefig()`. There is no save for pie chart. If I do a [search for oo pie chart](http://matplotlib.org/search.html?q=oo+pie+chart) there is also no results.

Comment: I did find this one, going to test to see if it works better: [svg filter pie](http://matplotlib.org/examples/misc/svg_filter_pie.html).

Comment: @localhost: I bet it won't work better as it's still using pyplot, which is where the shared global state comes from. I've added an untested code sample of how I would imagine a working code would look like. Note that it doesn't use pylab or pyplot at all.

Comment: Thanks for posting your sample, I posted my current answer. I am not checking it as the **answer** until I am quite certain this resolves the issues encountered. It seems the `matplotlib.use("Svg")` may be assisting the library with better clean up that is not done completely by the `close('all')` although I am sure that also helps. Thanks again for your time with this  and I plan to see if this resolves the issue completely!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79173/discussion-between-localhost-and-sergey).

Comment: Please note that the following error is encountered applying the above code:
`File "--application_path--\pyramidapp\pyramidapp\views.py", line 32, in test_svg_view
fig.savefig(imgdata, format='svg')
File "--python_path--\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-win32.egg\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1476, in savefig
self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'print_figure'`